# Chrome extension (desktop) to make make all pages automatically 'reader mode'

Tags: chrome, reading

Is there a way to made Chrome go into a 'reader' mode like Evernote Clearly. Ideally an extension for Chrome or maybe a user script like Stylish.

[image: Evernote Clearly screenshot]

I'm aware of these extensions and Chrome's 'Distil Mode' but that reader mode is exited when you click on further links and doesn't start in that mode.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Readability for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/readability/oknpjjbmpnndlpmnhmekjpocelpnlfdi).

Its major drawback is that, unlike Evernote's discontinued Clearly, it sends the webpage to its own server which then returns a cleaner version. Consequently, pages behind a login cannot be processed.

Clearly would process pages locally, in the browser window itself.